# Indefinite covariance matrix, multivariate normal distribution, how to compute the variance of $X+Y+Z$

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, covariance

If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ each follows the standard normal distribution, and each
pair of them follows a bivariate normal distribution with a correlation
coefficient of $-\frac{2}{3}$. Now we have
$$
\operatorname*{var}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
X\\
Y\\
Z
\end{bmatrix}
\right)  =%
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3}\\
-\frac{2}{3} & 1 & -\frac{2}{3}\\
-\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=\mathbf{V}%
$$
However, $\mathbf{V}$ is an indefinite matrix, not a positive semidefinite
matrix. Thus, $\mathbf{V}$ can not be a covariance matrix. If $\mathbf{V}$ is
the covariance matrix
$$
\operatorname*{var}(X+Y+Z)=%
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3}\\
-\frac{2}{3} & 1 & -\frac{2}{3}\\
-\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & 1
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=-1<0
$$
Is it possible to compute the variance of $X+Y+Z$? My guess is that they do
not have a joint multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: It is for this reason $(X,Y,Z)$ cannot have a common correlation of $-2/3$. The common correlation must be in the range $\left [-\frac12,1 \right]$.

Comment: The variance/covariance matrix $V$i sn't in general the correlation coefficients matrix $C$. You switch from one to the other by equation $V=DCD$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the different standard deviations.

Comment: @StubbornAtom yeah, the lower bound is -1/2 for a joint multivariate normal distribution. -2/3 leads to the non-existence of joint normal distribution, Why ? Given the information, is it possible to compute the variance of X+Y+Z?

Comment: Nothing to do with multivariate normal distribution. The given information is not correct as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Any covariance matrix $\mathbf{V}$ is symmetric and positive semi-definite and
its main diagonal contains variances (i.e., the covariance of each element
with itself). The correlation matrix is
$$
\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{VD}^{-\frac{1}{2}}%
$$
where $\mathbf{D}=\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{V})$ is the matrix of the diagonal
elements of $\mathbf{V}$. Thus, the correlation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ must be
**positive semi-definite**. If $\rho_{XY}=\rho_{XZ}=-\frac{2}{3}$, there must be $-\frac{1}{9}\leq\rho_{YZ}\leq1$, not $-1\leq\rho_{YZ}\leq1$, we can never take $\rho_{YZ}=-\frac{2}{3}$.